# Conectar com Mysql universal win 10

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Gostaria de uma ajuda, pois eu gostaria de saber como eu faço para pegar informações de um banco de dados Mysql e que serão assumidas por uma textblock. teriam como me ajudar com o código que faz isso?

EX: No Banco de Dados nome = João a  textblock sera joão.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> **Embora este método de conexão tenha sido [descontinuado](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-rt.html) vou postar uma resposta caso seja útil**

Baixe e instale os seguintes arquivos (win64): 
https://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.54-winx64.msi
https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Net/mysql-connector-net-6.7.9.msi

Para evitar erros de `Encoding Exception` selecione:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Crie um projeto `UWP` e adicione uma referência para `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.7.X\Assemblies\RT\MySql.Data.RT.dll`

Para conectar e consultar os dados da sua tabela:

```
using (_connection = new MySqlConnection("Database=test;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=teste;SslMode=None;"))
{
    _connection.Open();
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand("select name from user where id=1", _connection);
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            TextBlockName.Text = (reader.GetString("name"));
        }
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Fonte:**
https://github.com/rubgithub/MySqlUWP

**Referências:** 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-rt.html
https://blogs.oracle.com/MySqlOnWindows/entry/how_to_using_connector_net
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38785440/connecting-to-mysql-database-error-uwp-c