# Problema com Conexão ao Banco de Dados

Tags: c#, mysql, banco-de-dados

Poderiam me ajudar a descobrir porque esta dando esse erro?

Código:

```
using (_connection = new MySqlConnection("Database=test;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=teste;SslMode=None;"))
{
    _connection.Open();
    var cmd = new MySqlCommand("select name from user where id=1", _connection);
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            textBlock.Text = (reader.GetString("name"));
        }
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não esqueça de avaliar e aceitar a resposta da sua pergunta anterior: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188832/conectar-com-mysql-universal-win-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adicione o código abaixo antes de abrir a conexão:

```
System.Text.EncodingProvider ppp;
ppp = System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);
```

---

Resposta baseada [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471058/windows-1252-is-not-supported-encoding-name-c-sharp).